# suse nagios-nrpe-server

Tags: nagios, suse

I'm trying hard to figure out where YaST installed the `nagios-nrpe-server` on my SuSe system.
Actually I'm working on Debian and there this server is installed on `/etc/init.d`, the config data is on both systems on `/etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg`

I tried `find / -name nagios-nrpe-server` but it didn't work, and yes I'm sure it's installed and running.

`ps -ef | grep nagios-nrpe-server` gives me:

> root     24707 21985  0 15:07 pts/0    00:00:00 grep nagios-nrpe-server

Comment: Try installing `nagios-nrpe` package.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, you're wrong.
The output of the ps/grep command shows itself, i.e. the "grepping" of the ps output.
If that line is the only output of your grep command, then nagios-nrpe-server is not running.

Try this:

```
ps -fea | grep nagios-nrpe-server | grep -v grep
```

to remove any lines having to do with grep.

Answer (score 0):

You should look for the nrpe-Client in /etc/xinetd.d/

If nrpe isn't installed as a deamon you should find it under /usr/local/

If you wan't to make sure nrpe is up after restart:

Add NRPE as a service to the linux machine# vi /etc/services

Add the following

```
### EDIT NAGIOS START
nrpe            5666/tcp   # NRPE
### EDIT NAGIOS END
```

Don't forget to edit your firewall and add your nagios-server to the allowed hosts in your nrpe.cfg.